# When running "python main.py" does the python compiler compile the whole file into bytecode or compile and execute it line by line?

Tags: python, bytecode

When running "python main.py" does the python compiler compile the whole file into bytecode and then execute it line by line or compile and execute it line by line?

For example, let's say I have this `main.py`:

```py
print("Hello")

def foo():
    print("fooo()")

foo()
```

And I run `python main.py` in my terminal.
Does it first compile everything into bytecode and then execute that byte code line by line? Or does it compile it line by line too and execute it?

Because I know that for example when I just open the python console, I can run things line by line so they have to be compiled line by line(at least I think so? Tell me if I am correct or not). But what when I run a whole file?

Answer (score 4):

It first compiles it to byte code then interprets the generated code. Doing otherwise would be extremely inefficient.

See [What are .pyc files in Python?](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/What-are-pyc-files-in-Python): ".pyc files are created by the Python interpreter when a .py file is imported. They contain the "compiled bytecode" of the imported module/program so that the "translation" from source code to bytecode (which only needs to be done once) can be skipped on subsequent imports if the .pyc is newer than the corresponding .py file, thus speeding startup a little. But it's still interpreted. Once the *.pyc file is generated, there is no need of *.py file, unless you edit it."

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Thank you. Do you maybe know some nice resources when I can learn more? I find it weirdly hard to find more knowledge on more advanced python topics